# How to strip newlines from each line during a file read?

Tags: python, string, file-io

I'm reading lines from a file that contains one[*] word/line, such as:

```
dog
cat
person
tree
```

Each of these words also contains a newline `\n` character. I want to read them into a list and throw away the newlines. The way I've devised is to read with `readlines()` and then process the list to `strip()` the newlines:

```
with open('words.txt') as f:
    words = f.readlines()

for index, word in enumerate(words):
    words[index] = word.strip()
```

This works fine, but I can't help thinking there's a more efficient way to do this, to strip the newlines during the read process. But I can't find a way. Is there something more efficient (while also considering readability, etc.)

[*] UPDATE: I should have mentioned that some lines may contain more than one word, and in those cases however many words are on a line should go into a single list item. Both answers so far handle this (as does my own code), but I wanted to mention it.

Comment: You can do it like this:
# ble is one column file:

    lista = [] 
    with open("ble", "r") as f: 
        for i in f: 
            i = i.strip() 
            lista.append(i)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
with open('words.txt') as f:
    words = [word.strip() for word in f]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `map`:

```
with open('words.txt') as f:
   words = map(str.rstrip, f)
```

Comment: rstrip, if you want to be even more precise :) (not that it's needed or anything)

Comment: And even `rstrip("\n")` to remove only the newline character (or `rstrip("\n\r")` to remove both newline and carriage return).

Answer (score 2):

You could write: `lines = [s.rstrip("\n\r") for s in f.readlines()]` (notice it's not just `strip`, which will do more than remove EOL characters).

However, if your file is large, you should maybe process each line in a loop, rather than laoding the whole file, for example as in:

```
while True:
    s = f.readline()
    if s == "":
        break   # end of file
    line = s.rstrip("\n\r")
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

For handling more than one word per line you may want to split the line.

```
with open('words.txt') as f:
    result = [words.strip().split() for words in f]
```

This will create a list of lists, most of which are one element long. So, for example you could do this.

```
for words in result:
    print len(words)
```