# Getting rid of "\r" when converting file to a list in python

Tags: python

I have an `Excel` file that looks like the following:

```
First_Name  Initials    Last_Name   Places  Email   Tel Fax Joint   Corresponding   Experimental design Data generation Data processing Data analysis   Statistical analysis    Manuscript preparation
Anna    A   Karenina    BioInform_Harvard   anna.Karenina@ucsf.edu  8885006000  8885006001  1       Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y
Konstantin  D   Levin   Neuro_Harvard   Konstantin.levin@childrens.harvard.edu  8887006000  8887006001  1               Y   Y   Y   
Alexei  K   Vronsky IGM_Columbia    alexei.vronsky@cumc.columbia.edu    8889006000  8889006001  2           Y               
Stepan  A   Oblonsky    NIMH    steoblon@mail.nih.gov   8891006000  8891006001  2       Y                   Y
```

In my `Python` code, to open the file i have written code as follows:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for i in f:
        i = i.rstrip().split("\t")
        print(i)
```

The resulting list looks as follows. How do I get rid of the `'\r'`? I've tried various methods like replacing "\r" with "", but that messes up the elements of the list that look like `'Y\rKonstantin'`.

```
['First_Name', 'Initials', 'Last_Name', 'Places', 'Email', 'Tel', 'Fax', 'Joint', 'Corresponding', 'Experimental design', 'Data generation', 'Data processing', 'Data analysis', 'Statistical analysis', 'Manuscript preparation\rAnna', 'A', 'Karenina', 'BioInform_Harvard', 'anna.Karenina@ucsf.edu', '8885006000', '8885006001', '1', '', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y\rKonstantin', 'D', 'Levin', 'Neuro_Harvard', 'Konstantin.levin@childrens.harvard.edu', '8887006000', '8887006001', '1', '', '', '', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', '\rAlexei', 'K', 'Vronsky', 'IGM_Columbia', 'alexei.vronsky@cumc.columbia.edu', '8889006000', '8889006001', '2', '', '', 'Y', '', '', '', '\rStepan']
```

I'm able to get rid of newline characters fine, but it's the `'\r'` I can't get rid of.

Comment: why `rstrip` and not `strip`?try executing `'\rAlexei'.strip()`. On the other hand, you can use map to convert all the string in list

Comment: You should use `'\n\r'`

Comment: `i.rstrip("\n\r")`.

Comment: Also `f.read().striplines()` can give you want you need

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to strip newlines from each line during a file read?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18865210/how-to-strip-newlines-from-each-line-during-a-file-read)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24946640/removing-r-n-from-a-python-list-after-importing-with-readlines

Comment: I've tried the above solutions and those in similar questions, but nothing is working. Things look fine when I do some variation of "strip" or "rstrip" first, but then when I split by tab, the "\r" is introduced again. I tried first splitting by tab and then doing strip too but that doesn't work either.

Comment: This looks like a TSV so why don't you just use the built-in [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module and let it do the proper parsing for you?

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key thing to notice is that python only reads one big line with all the `\r` characters embedded within. Based on that, I'm guessing you're using Python 2.x, which didn't enable [universal newlines](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines) mode by default. Changing your mode to `rU` should do what you're expecting:

```
with open(filename, 'rU') as f:
    for i in f:
        i = i.rstrip().split("\t")
        print(i)
```

For more information, see the [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

as suggested, the `csv` module is good for dealing with this sort of data.  I'd do something like:

```
import csv

with open(filename) as fd:
  inp = csv.reader(fd, delimiter='\t')

  header = next(inp)
  print(header)

  for row in inp:
    print(row)
```

Python has support for magic [universal newlines](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines) which means it does something sensible with "old-style" Mac line-endings by default.  your can then use the `csv` module with a custom delimiter to parse the tab delimited file